# Andriod - Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting tired of fixing this problem. Always show me this error

```
Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText.
```

I don't understand how to fix this problem. Already tried many StackOverflow answers but failed.
Using **Gradle 7.1.0 version**. Device **Pixel 4 API 27**.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryLight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/hint_id"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/material_dynamic_neutral10"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Error message:

```
2022-02-02 17:05:04.720 9809-9809/com.example.magicidapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.magicidapplication, PID: 9809
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.magicidapplication/com.example.magicidapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class EditText
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
```

Comment: Can you show your Java code please ?

Comment: What's the value of "@color/material_dynamic_neutral10"

Comment: @SiddarthJain #191C1E

Comment: The problem is in this color destination. First try adding it manually like this
`android:textColorHint="#191C1E"`

Comment: @FrancescoD'OnorioDeMeo [link](https://ideone.com/zpi4K7)

Comment: @SiddarthJain added default color still gives the same error.

Comment: @RokibulHasan Now you should try addin simple edittext without other properties. Then add each properties one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the stacktrace `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1` there is some issue in the `@color/material_dynamic_neutral10` color change it to something else or remove it

Comment: Still gives the same error message.

Comment: @RokibulHasan you removed the color ?

Comment: No changes that to white. @TaranmeetSingh

Comment: @RokibulHasan try to compile by removing the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you have issue in your color. try changing color
**android:textColorHint="@color/material_dynamic_neutral10"**

Comment: Already mentioned that